# Concrete examples of elliptic pseudo-differential equations

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, reference-works, pseudo-differential-operators

Remember that $p \in S^{m}_{1,0}(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n)$ or that  $p: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a simbol if it is a smooth function such that
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle |D^\alpha_{\xi} D^\beta_{x} p(x,\xi)| \leq C_{\alpha , \beta}(1+|\xi|)^{m-|\alpha|}
\end{align*}
then the associated psuedo-differential operator is
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle p(x,D_x)f=\mathrm{OP}(p)f=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{i x \cdot \xi}p(x,\xi) \widehat{f}(\xi) d\xi 
\end{align*}
where $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. For example if $c_\alpha \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n):=C^{\infty}_b$ and we consider
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle p(x,\xi)=\sum_{|\alpha| \leq m} c_{\alpha}(x) \xi^\alpha 
\end{align*}
then $p \in S^{m}_{1,0}(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n)$ and using Fourier transform we have that
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle p(x, D_x)f = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq m} c_{\alpha}(x) D^{\alpha}_x f
\end{align*}
for each $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and any differential operator with limited regular coefficients is a pseudo-differential operator. We say that the simbol $p \in S^{m}_{1,0}(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n)$ is elliptic if $|p(x,\xi)| \geq C|\xi|^m$, and consequently the pseudo-differential operator is said elliptic. Therefore we can consider the elliptic pseudo-elliptic differential equation:
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle p(x, D_x)u = f
\end{align*}
where for example we assume that $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Clearly the Laplace operator is also an elliptic pseudo-differential operator.

My question is: which other concrete examples and "famous"  (as Laplace operator) of elliptic pseudo-differential operators are there? thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps, the most famous one is the *fractional Laplacian*
$$
(-\Delta)^{s/2}u(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\mathrm{e}^{ix\xi}|\xi|^s\hat u(\xi)\,d\xi.
$$
A version for periodic functions is
$$
|\partial_x|^a u(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}|k|^a\mathrm{e}^{ikx}\hat u_k
$$
whenever $\,u(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\mathrm{e}^{ikx}\hat u_k$.

Comment: Do you know any other examples? Not necessarily very famous but having applications, do you have any reference? thank you